# POST request to Mixcloud

Tags: php, mixcloud

I have a PHP script that POSTs to Mixcloud and receiving an error I have not been able to resolve.

This is using PHP 7.3.6 and curl as I've seen in other posts as example.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.mixcloud.com/upload/?access_token=$mixcloud");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 * 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
// load json response into array
$res = json_decode($server_output, true);
echo print_r( $post, true );
echo print_r($res, true);
```

The upload fails with the following post that was sent:

```
Array
(
    [mp3] => @/var/share_ro/fullshow/surface.mp3
    [name] => Upload title
    [description] => Upload description
    [picture] => @/var/share_ro/fullshow/avatar.png
    [tags-0-tag] => Tag1
    [tags-1-tag] => Tag2
    [tags-2-tag] => Tag3
    [tags-3-tag] => Tag4
    [tags-4-tag] => Tag5
)
```

and response:

```
Array
(
    [details] => Array
        (
            [mp3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => This field is required.
                )

        )

    [error] => Array
        (
            [message] =>
            [type] => PostValidationError
        )

)
```

However, the full path to the file does exist and I have tried with and without the leading `@` on the file name:

```
$ ls -lah /var/share_ro/fullshow/surface.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 user mp3 79M Jun 11 16:08 /var/share_ro/fullshow/surface.mp3
```

Can someone see what it is I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using curl in a shell script, works fine:

```
$script = "/home/user/code/scripts/mixcloud.sh";
$server_output = shell_exec("$script $mixcloud $mp3 '$name' '$host' '$title' '$desc' '$picfile' $tag1 $tag2");
```

And the script being:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to upload file to Mixcloud - see send_to_mixcloud function in make_fullshow.php
TOKEN=$1
MP3=$2
NAME=$3
ARTIST=$4
ALBUM=$5
DESC=$6
PIC=$7
TAG1=$8
TAG2=$9
TAG3=${10}
TAG4=${11}
TAG5=${12}
curl -F "mp3=@$MP3" \
 -F "name=$NAME" \
 -F "picture=@$PIC" \
 -F "description=$DESC" \
 -F "tags-0-tag=$TAG1" \
 -F "tags-1-tag=$TAG2" \
 -F "tags-2-tag=$TAG3" \
 -F "tags-3-tag=$TAG4" \
 -F "tags-4-tag=$TAG5" \
 https://api.mixcloud.com//upload/?access_token=$TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0):

I returned to try to use [this script](https://gist.github.com/jurajseffer/6770964) I found years ago but it was no longer working for me with exactly the same error message you had. Your answer helped me a lot, but I thought I'd post this "simplification" to your work that is working for me. Does exactly the same, just doesn't require the external shell script file.

```php
$script = 'curl';
foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
  $script .= " -F \"$key=$value\"";
}
$script .= " https://api.mixcloud.com/upload/?access_token={$token}";
$server_output = shell_exec($script);
```